# MySQL - If NOT EXIST return 0

Tags: mysql

right now I have pretty big query which looks like:

```
    $sql = "SELECT c.vin, c.case_id, c.claimnumber, c.platenumber, c.axrmrs_id, c.insurer_memberid, c.country, c.date_created, c.totalloss, c.lastcalc_manufacturer_code, c.lastcalc_model_code, c.lastcalc_submodel_code, c.audavin_triggered, c.accident_date, c.registration_date, c.manufacturing_year,
              cl.spareparts, cl.totalcosts, cl.laborhours, cl.laborcosts, cl.calculationdate, cl.paintlabor, cl.paintmaterial, cl.currency, car.manufacturer, car.model, car.submodel, org.name
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod LIKE 'L%',po.text,NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textL,
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod LIKE 'E',po.text,NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textE
            FROM axnmrs_cases AS c
              LEFT JOIN axnmrs_calculations as cl on c.case_id = cl.case_id AND c.country = cl.country
              LEFT JOIN axnmrs_positions as po on c.case_id = po.case_id
              LEFT JOIN car_type as car on car.manufacturer_code = c.lastcalc_manufacturer_code AND car.main_type = c.lastcalc_model_code AND car.subtype_code = c.lastcalc_submodel_code
              LEFT JOIN organization_list as org on org.memberId = c.insurer_memberid
            WHERE c.vin= :vin
              GROUP BY c.vin, c.case_id, c.axrmrs_id";
```

I have small problem that my last `LEFT JOIN` QUERY not always return `org.name` (this is short list so not all IDs are there). 
However I want to return something like `0` if `org.name` doesn't EXIST.

Can someone help me how should I do this without breaking `LEFT JOIN` logic?

Thank you

Kind Regards

Andurit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce` function:

```
SELECT c.vin, c.case_id, c.claimnumber, c.platenumber, c.axrmrs_id, c.insurer_memberid, c.country, c.date_created, c.totalloss, c.lastcalc_manufacturer_code, c.lastcalc_model_code, c.lastcalc_submodel_code, c.audavin_triggered, c.accident_date, c.registration_date, c.manufacturing_year,
                  cl.spareparts, cl.totalcosts, cl.laborhours, cl.laborcosts, cl.calculationdate, cl.paintlabor, cl.paintmaterial, cl.currency, car.manufacturer, car.model, car.submodel, 

                  COALESCE(org.name, 0) as name -- <--- Check this !!!

                  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod LIKE 'L%',po.text,NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textL,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod LIKE 'E',po.text,NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textE
                FROM axnmrs_cases AS c
                  LEFT JOIN axnmrs_calculations as cl on c.case_id = cl.case_id AND c.country = cl.country
                  LEFT JOIN axnmrs_positions as po on c.case_id = po.case_id
                  LEFT JOIN car_type as car on car.manufacturer_code = c.lastcalc_manufacturer_code AND car.main_type = c.lastcalc_model_code AND car.subtype_code = c.lastcalc_submodel_code
                  LEFT JOIN organization_list as org on org.memberId = c.insurer_memberid
                WHERE c.vin= :vin
                  GROUP BY c.vin, c.case_id, c.axrmrs_id
```

you could also use `IFNULL` instead of `COALESCE`, in this case they are the same. They return the first parameter that is not null. e.g. `coalesce(null,5)` = 5, `coalesce(3, 5) = 3`. The difference between isnull and coalesce is that coalesce can receive more parameters.

Answer (score 2):

use `IFNULL(org.name, 0)` in your select.

Comment: hey @mikeb thank you for your answer it works perfect  so you have THUMB UP for it, however Roberto was first so to stay fair I mark his answer as correct.